# Get default series color in code behind for LineSeries2D for DevExpress ChartControl

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress, series, brush

I have some `LineSeries2D` elements inside a `XYDiagram2D.Series`. I want to get the `Brush` property in code behind. When I try the code below the series brush property is null. Only If I set the brush property in XAML apperantly I get the right result. But If I don't set this in XAML I would expect to get the `Brush` with which the Series is colored by default instead of null.

```
<dxc:XYDiagram2D.Series>
    <dxc:LineSeries2D ArgumentScaleType="Numerical" x:Name="series"
                                          ArgumentDataMember="Time"
                                          ValueDataMember="Value"
                                          DataSource="{Binding Path=ListaChart}">      
    </dxc:LineSeries2D>

    <dxc:LineSeries2D ArgumentScaleType="Numerical" x:Name="series1"
                                          ArgumentDataMember="Time"
                                          ValueDataMember="Value"
                                          DataSource="{Binding Path=ListaChart2}">
    </dxc:LineSeries2D>
</dxc:XYDiagram2D.Series>
```

and in code behind:

```
chart.UpdateData();
chart.UpdateLayout();

foreach (var targetSeries in chart.Diagram.Series.OfType<LineSeries2D>())
{
    vm.SelectedChannelBrush = targetSeries.Brush;
}

if (PNUsLB.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    vm.SelectedChannelBrush = series.Brush;
}
else
{
    vm.SelectedChannelBrush = series1.Brush;
}
```

The name of the `ChartControl` is "chart". My problem is `series.Brush`, `series1.Brush` and `targetSeries.Brush` are null after the charts are drawn at runtime.
So how do I get the default series color in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same thing on mind today. 
To change the color of the brush you have to handle a Event that is thrown from the chart control.

1. Your Chart should be able to fire Events:

   ```
   chartControl.CustomDrawCrosshair+=new CustomDrawCrosshairEventHandler(chartControl_CustomDrawCrosshair);
   ```
2. Handle the fired Event with a function:

   ```
   public void chartControl_CustomDrawCrosshair(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.CustomDrawCrosshairEventArgs e)
   {
        e.CrosshairLineElement.Brush = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue;
   }
   ```

Here are all Windows colors that you can use for the Brushes:

[image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC24340.png]

Best Wishes,
Mijat

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the `palette` property. You should find [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfChartsChartControl_Palettetopic) a complete answer.

Comment: I am using WPF ChartControl, not ASP.NET control. Also I don't see any View property on the series.

Comment: I fixed my answer (sorry) :)

Comment: I didn't manage to get the colors in the pallet (I don't want define a CustomPallet like in that example). I want to get the default Brushes used. Also for each brush I need to know to which channel it belongs to. I think there should be something on the LineSeries2D object not on the ChartControl.